# Minimum length subsequence with positive sum <= K

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, subsequence, minimum-size

The opposite question:

> Maximum length subsequence with positive-sum <= K is in fact the
>   standard 01 Knapsack problem.

The solution for it is pretty straightforward:

```
int solve(const vector<int> &A, int K) {
    int dp[A.size()+1][K+1];
    int i, j;

    // Base Cases
    for(i=0; i<= K; i++)
        dp[0][i] = 0;
    for(i=0; i<= A.size(); i++)
        dp[i][0] = 0;


    for(i=1; i <= A.size(); i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<= K; j++)
        {
            dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
            if(A[i-1] <= j)
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i][j], 1 + dp[i-1][j-A[i-1]]);
        }
    }
    return dp[A.size()][K]
```

I am having a tough time thinking how *Minimum length subsequence with sum <= K* could be implemented along the same lines.

Example:

```
A = [14, 10, 4]
K = 14
Minimum Length Subsequence = 14
Maximum Length Subsequence = 10, 4 (Arrived from Knapsack)
```

Its certainly not as easy as just changing the max to min as then the answer shall always be the base case. Which leads me to think, Do we need to tweak the base case? I am stuck here and need some push.

Any ideas on how one should be solving this problem?

Comment: If the input size allows it, you can use a sieve for this, but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: What's the answer for `K = 14`, `A = [11, 1, 1, 1]` ? The "opposite" question, as you propose, seems only similar to 0-1 knapsack if you assign a value to an element's participation in the solution (that way more elements means more value, assuming you're comparing the knapsack weight to the sum).

Comment: Also "closest" is unclear. Could the sum in the solution be slightly greater than K?

Comment: @m69 Could you please elaborate by what you mean by sieve?

Comment: @גלעדברקן By closest we mean less than or equal to. Answer for `A = [11, 1, 1, 1], K = 14` is `[11,1,1,1]`

Answer (score 1):

Replace the sums with ordered pairs `(sum, length)`.  And now apply the previous algorithm that you know.  Order is lexicographic, by sum then by length.  You are trying to come close to `(target_sum, 0)`.

The closest "sum" now will be the shortest subsequence with minimum positive difference.

Comment: What's the answer for K = 14, A = [11, 1, 1, 1]? It's entirely unclear which dimension is primary, shortness or closeness.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Primary dimension is to get the sum <= K (closeness) and which is as short as possible. Its entirely like Knapsack: Get the maximum profit while capturing maximum weight below the threshold. Just here, we want minimum and not maximum.

Comment: @גלעדברקן For what I described, it is the shortest of the ones with minimum positive difference.  So closeness is primary.  However that said, a variety of tradeoffs between the dimensions can be achieved by putting a different ordering on the pairs.

Comment: @btilly Could you please elaborate a bit more? 
Is there any way of doing this without a pair?

Comment: @user248884 Just replace one type of number with another.  Done.  There are other approaches, but they require more work.

Comment: @btilly Thanks for your answer. I have tried your approach and it seems to work. I am having a tough time though connecting the dots. How did you arrive at this approach? What was your thought process? Even after implementing the problem, I am still unclear as to why this approach is different (in terms of data structure usage) from the Knapsack problem. Given to think about this problem in a test setting, I dont know how I would've thought about this. Hence, please also elaborate on your thought process.

Comment: @user248884 It is a trick that I've used before.  For example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307893/determine-if-a-given-weighted-graph-has-unique-mst.  Before that, my background is math.  So thinking of number systems in terms of their properties sort of comes naturally for me.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet below shows what I mean by a sieve. It's a simple solution, and probably not useful for large input. It's not like the sieves to find primes, which only contain true or false, but more like a dictionary of combinations and their sum, like e.g.:

```
{value: 14, components: [4, 10]}
```

If you're unfamiliar with Javascript, arrays behave more like associative arrays or dictionaries with string keys (that's why the `Number` conversion is needed), and `for in` only iterates over the elements that have a value if the array is sparse. Also, `slice` and `concat` create a copy of the array.

```js
function minSub(array, target) {
    var sieve = [[]];
    for (var i in array) {
        var temp = [];
        for (var j in sieve) {
            var val = Number(j) + array[i];
            if (!sieve[val] || sieve[val].length > sieve[j].length + 1) {
                temp[val] = sieve[j].concat([array[i]]);
            }
        }
        for (var j in temp) {
            if (Number(j) <= target) {
                sieve[j] = temp[j].slice();
            }
        }
    }
    var max = 0;
    for (var j in sieve) {
        if (Number(j) > max) {
            max = Number(j);
        }
    }
    return sieve[max];
}

console.log(minSub([4, 10, 14], 14));
console.log(minSub([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], 8));
```

Note that, contrary to what I suggested in a comment, sorting the input in descending order doesn't guarantee that the simplest combination to form a value is found first; you have to check the number of components whenever you encounter a value already present in the sieve; e.g. with the input:

```
{8, 4, 3, 2, 1}
```

You'd find the combination:

```
{value: 9, components: [4, 3, 2]}
```

before finding:

```
{value: 9, components: [8, 1]}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this approach wont work for large inputs but its a great approach to know. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @user248884 this approach is far more efficient for reasonable input size when the range and K are large. Consider that the range is a factor in your current formulation, `O(|A| * K)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is along the lines of what you're looking for. We have to be more careful than in your formulation of maximum subsequence in checking whether or not a sum can be reached. In this formulation `dp[i][j]` is the smallest subsequence summing to `j`, considering elements up to `A[i]` (so `i` is not subsequence length).

JavaScript code (only lightly tested):

```js
function solve(A, K) {
  let i,j;

  let dp = new Array(length);

  for (i=0; i<A.length; i++)
    dp[i] = new Array(K + 1);

  // Base Cases
  for(i=0; i<A.length; i++)
    dp[i][0] = 0;

  for (i=0; i<A.length; i++){
    // Exact match
    if (A[i] == K)
      return 1;

    // We can reach this sum with only one element
    if (A[i] < K)
      dp[i][A[i]] = 1;
    
    // There are no previously achieved sums
    if (i == 0)
      continue;
    
    for (j=1; j<=K; j++){
      dp[i][j] = dp[i][j] || dp[i - 1][j];

      if (A[i] <= j){
        dp[i][j] = Math.min(
          dp[i][j] || Infinity,
          1 + (dp[i - 1][j - A[i]] || Infinity)
        );
      }
    }
  }
  
  for (i=K; i>=0; i--)
    if (![undefined, Infinity].includes(dp[A.length - 1][i]))
      return dp[A.length - 1][i];
}

console.log(solve([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 11));
console.log(solve([14,10,4], 14));
console.log(solve([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0], 8));
console.log(solve([7,7,2,3],15))
```

Comment: Sorry if for my lack of authority on this code logic, but I think if `(i == 0)
      continue;` is redundant?

Comment: @user248884 why do you think so?